# Problem with triple boot system

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, windows-10, secure-boot, kali

Got a new laptop with one NVMe drive and one SSD drive and wanted to do the following:

Have one encrypted Ubuntu partition and one encrypted (with Bitlocker) windows-partition, both on the NVMe drive.
Have one encrypted Kali Linux partition on the SSD.

I setup the Ubuntu partition and the Windows partition without problems and everything worked just fine. The only caveat is that on the few occasions that I have to boot into Windows I have to do so by changing boot order in the BIOS (because of the Bitlocker encryption I guess).

I used the computer like this for a couple of days and then I went ahead and installed Kali Linux on the separate SSD as one encrypted partition on the whole drive.

Everything worked fine, but I had to change boot order in the BIOS to boot into Kali as well (probably due to misconfiguration?), but as I had to do the same for windows (not due to misconfiguration?) I didn't see it as a problem.

Then all of a sudden I couldn't access BIOS anymore! It's an Acer laptop and I thought it had something to do with BIOS itself. If I just started the system it launched grub and I could boot into Ubuntu normally and all, but whenever I tried to enter BIOS on launch the computer froze on the Acer splash screen and nothing happened. I couldn't get it to work but then all of a sudden BIOS launched normally but the Kali partition was gone from the boot order menu.

I'm thinking "Well I'll just reinstall it and see" but when I try to boot into the other partitions they have stopped working as well. The Windows partition won't boot at all, and when I try to boot into Ubuntu it says something like "cryptsetup waiting on encrypted device" and stays there.

What am I doing wrong? I'm almost certain that I have to do a complete reinstall of all partitions, but I don't want this to happen again! What crucial part of this setup am I missing?

I've tried to find answers to this problem on the web of course, but I can't (I think at least) find something with this setup and these kinds of problems. I don't know whether it's a case of some misconfiguration in BIOS or with the encryption (entries in crypttab) or maybe with one of the drives.

It turns out that BIOS had somehow reverted to a state in which RST had been enabled instead of AHCI, which caused these problems to occur. I just enabled AHCI again and now everything works to some degree. What I mean by that is that Kali can no longer boot without secure boot being disabled. So the question is whether this was the cause initially or if I just have to keep Secure Boot disabled.

Comment: UEFI updates may reset system to defaults. Windows updates also changes some settings including turning back on fast start up and resetting boot order. Reinstall or major update of grub may also reset boot order. So with multiple installs you have to keep track or only use one grub.